# Determining Issue With Retrieving JSON from URL in iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsurlconnection, nsstringencoding

Let me start off by saying that I am not particularly trying to find a solution, just the root cause of the problem. I am trying to retrieve a JSON from a url. In browser, the url call works just fine and I am able to see the entire JSON without issue. However, in x-code when simply using NSURLConnection, I am getting data bytes, but my NSString is null.

```
    theString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

After doing some research I have found that I am probably trying to use the wrong encoding.  I am not sure what type of encoding is being used by the url, so on first instinct I just tried some random encoding types.

```
    NSString* myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSString* myString2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding];
    NSString* myString3 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding];
```

NSASCIIStringEncoding and NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding is able to bring back a partially correct JSON.  It is not the entire JSON thatI am able to view in the browser, and some characters are a little messed up, but it is something.  To try and better determine what encoding was used, I decided to use the following method to try and determine it by looking at what encoding returned.

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSStringEncoding encoding;
NSString *my_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url
                                                 usedEncoding:&encoding
                                                        error:&error];
```

My NSStringEncoding value is 3221214344. And this number is consistent everytime I run the app.  I can not find any NSStringEncoding values that even come close to matching this.

My final question is: Is the encoding used for this url not consumable by iOS, is it possible that multiple types of encoding was used for this url, or is there something else that I could be doing wrong on my end?

Comment: Can you share the URL that exposes the problem?

Comment: What encoding does your browser say the results are using?

Comment: Proxi, sorry, because of confidentiality reasons I do not think I can share the url. And rmaddy, how can I view what encoding is being used by the browser? I am using chrome atm.

Comment: I don't use Chrome so I don't know. Under Safari you can go to the View menu then Text Encoding.

Comment: BTW - when you used `initWithContentsOfURL:usedEncoding:error:` did you get a valid string? If so, why not used that? Just use GCD to run in the background.

Comment: The text encoding under safari with my url simply says default. And I am getting null back for string there as well.

Comment: Sorry small update, in chrome, the encoding list is greyed out, but has western iso-8859-1 checked. Tried the json call now and it seems to be working ok.

Comment: can you log the "error description", with this + (instancetype)stringWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)url usedEncoding:(NSStringEncoding *)enc error:(NSError **)error call. it seem like there is some encoding error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best not to rely on Cocoa to figure out the string encoding if possible, especially if the data might be corrupted. A better approach would be to check if the value indicated by the HTTP Content-Type header specifies a character set like in this example:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-4
```

Once you're able to parse and retrieve a character set name from the Content-Type header, you need to convert it to an `NSStringEncoding`, first by passing it to `CFStringConvertIANACharSetNameToEncoding`, and then passing the returned CF string encoding to `CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding`. After that, you can initialize your string using `-[NSString initWithData:encoding:]`.

```
NSData *HTTPResponseBody = …; // Get the HTTP response body
NSString *charSetName = …;  // Get a charset name from the Content-Type HTTP header

// Get the Core Foundation string encoding
CFStringEncoding cfencoding = CFStringConvertIANACharSetNameToEncoding((CFStringRef)charSetName);

// Confirm this is a known encoding
if (cfencoding != kCFStringEncodingInvalidId) {
    // Initialize the string
    NSStringEncoding nsencoding = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(cfencoding);
    NSString *JSON = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: HTTPResponseBody 
                                           encoding: nsencoding];
}
```

You still may run into problems if the string data you're working with is corrupted. For example, in the above code snippet, perhaps `charSetName` is UTF-8, but `HTTPResponseBody` can't be parsed as UTF-8 because there's an invalid byte sequence. In this situation, Cocoa will return `nil` when you try to instantiate your string, and short of sanitizing the data so that it conforms to the reported string encoding (perhaps by stripping out invalid byte sequences), you may want to report an error back to the end user.

As a last-ditch effort — rather than reporting an error — you *could* initialize a string using an encoding that can handle anything you throw at it, such as `NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding`. The one caveat here is that unicode / corrupted data may show up intermittently as symbols or unexpected alphanumerics.

Answer (score 1):

Even though it seems that the answer has been provided in the comments (using iso-8859-1 as the correct encoding) I thought it worthwhile to discuss how I would go about debugging this problem.

You said that the Desktop Browser (Chrome) can digest the data correctly, so let's use that:

1. Enable Developer Tools https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/
2. When the Dev Tools window is open, switch to "network" and execute your call in that browser tab
3. check the output by clicking on the request url - it should give you some clue.

If that doesn't work, tools like [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm) can help you to recreate the call before you implement it on the device